# CloudFormation, AWS Lambda: Ignore Parameter from Old Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying a .Net Core Web API project to AWS Lambda. It works, but I have the following issue:

**Previous Template Contains Parameter No Longer Used**

A previous deployment of our Lambda created a CloudFormation template with a defined `Parameter`. For discussion, let's call it "BadParameter".

Now, we don't want to use that parameter anymore. We've updated our `serverless.template` so that it does not have that parameter anymore.

Now, all our deployments (*using the update template*) fail with the message:

> Error creating CloudFormation change set: Parameters: [BadParameter]
>   do not exist in the template

I can fix this by downloading the template from CloudFormation, manually removing the parameter, then re-uploading the template, but that is tedious and error-prone.

*Is there some way I can specify in my new template that the old parameter should be deleted?*

Comment: Ideally, your CloudFormation templates should reflect the current state of your deployment, and you shouldn't deploy/modify anything in that environment outside of CloudFormation. Can you not simply remove the parameter from everywhere it's used in your source, including the CF template, and do a CloudFormation update to redeploy all relevant changes?

Comment: @jarmod that's exactly what I'm trying to do. The problem is, when I try update the template, it fails because the old version has a parameter the new one lacks. The only way seems to be to first update the existing template manually.

Comment: I don't think the cause of the failure is that the previous version of the template includes the parameter (otherwise you could never delete parameters). The docs suggest that you can delete a template parameter *unless* it is used by a resource that does not support updates. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this too. I'm going to give details on what I saw and what I did to fix it because my situation doesn't seem to be exactly the same as SouthShoreAK's situation, but is close enough that I'm certain we are experiencing the same issue.

### Situation and Error

parent-template.yml is a CloudFormation template which is being deployed as part of the CI/CD process. Inside this template are several AWS::CloudFormation::StackSet resources, child-template-1.yml, child-template-2.yml, etc. Each child-template-*.yml StackSet resource is deploying into multiple accounts.

I was receiving this error on one of the AWS::CloudFormation::StackSet resources:

> Parameters: [OldParameter1, OldParameter2] do not exist in the template

### Changes Which Caused the Error

Recent changes were:

1. In child-template-1.yml I removed these two parameters, OldParameter1 and OldParameter2.
2. In parent-template.yml in one of the AWS::CloudFormation::StackSet resources I had been passing in values for OldParamter1 and OldParameter2. I removed these two ParameterKey-ParameterValues. In other words, I stopped providing these parameters as inputs to the child template.

### Steps Taken

1. I went into child-template-1.yml and added the parameters OldParameter1 and OldParameter2 back into the template.
2. I gave both parameters a default value, "Dummy".
3. I re-deployed with `aws cloudformation deploy`
4. I went into child-template-1.yml and removed the parameters OldParameter1
   and OldParameter2.
5. I re-deployed

At that point, the parameters have been removed from the templates. I do not know why this is necessary; it seems like a bug in CloudFormation to me.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but I just ran into this myself using CodePipeline. I cant tell from the OP's question whether they were using it though.

The solution was to remove the old parameters from the json file referenced at `TemplateConfiguration` in the CodePipeline `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` stage.